# how to map serial and data points using json Array

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am creating multi serial line chart using highchart.

My `Json` (cleanData) look like this...

```
[{
    "key": "port_A",
    "value": [
        [1447596900000, 0],
        [1447596960000, 0],
        [1447597020000, 1]
    ]
}, {
    "key": "port_B",
    "value": [
        [1447596900000, 0],
        [1447596960000, 4]
    ]
} {
    "key": "port_C",
    "value": [
        [1447596900000, 0],
        [1447596960000, 0],
        [1447597020000, 1]
    }]
```

How can I map "key" as serial and "value" as data points on `highchart`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie',
            zoomType: 'y',
            resetZoomButton: {
                position: {
                    // align: 'right', // by default
                    // verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                    x: 0,
                    y: -30
                }
            },
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 50
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Users by region',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            //categories: ['APAC', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    'fontSize': '10px',
                        'fontFamily': 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        'color': '#333',
                        'text-transform': 'uppercase',
                        'font-weight': '600'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of users '
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '#users: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        series: []

    });


    var cleanData1 = JSON.stringify(myArray);
    var cleanData = $.parseJSON(cleanData1);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cleanData));
    chart.series = cleanData;

});
```

Comment: You know you are missing a `,` between: `} {` in you JSON?

Comment: There are two errors in the JSON. There is a missing `,` and a missing `]`

Use this JSON instead : `[ { "key": "port_A", "value": [ [ 1447596900000, 0 ], [ 1447596960000, 0 ], [ 1447597020000, 1 ] ] }, { "key": "port_B", "value": [ [ 1447596900000, 0 ], [ 1447596960000, 4 ] ] }, { "key": "port_C", "value": [ [ 1447596900000, 0 ], [ 1447596960000, 0 ], [ 1447597020000, 1 ] ] } ]`

Comment: you want pie chart or line chart ? in question you mentioned line chart but in your code its pie chart.

Comment: Am looking for line chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over your json and put the name and data in an object as like below

```
 var seriesData = [];
 $.each(clearData, function(i,item){
 seriesData.push({name:clearData[i].key,data:clearData[i].value});
  console.log("seriesData"+JSON.stringify(seriesData));
 });
```

[See working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/onhfLqdm/42/)